# Separating multiple query results

Tags: python, sql, impala

I am running multiple (about 60) queries in impala using impala shell from a file and outputting to a file. I am using :

```
impala-shell -q "query_here; query_here; etc;" -o output_path.csv -B --output_delimiter=','
```

The issue is that they are not separated between queries, so query 2 would be directly appended as a new row right onto the bottom of query 1. I need to separate the results to math them up with each query, however I do not know where each query's results are done and another begins because it is a continuous CSV file.

Is there a way to run multiple queries like this and leave some type of space or delimiter between query results or any way to separate the results by which query they came from?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just run them separately to begin with, into separate csv files?

Comment: I am not too informed about is so correct me if I am wrong, but I was under the impression that running them as one multiple query instead of a bunch of them separately would have some performance benefit.

I will also need to rejoin the separate CSV files in order to make some joins on their results with other query results.

Comment: Some potential but negligible performance benefit is pointless if the solution doesn't work to begin with.  Preemptive tuning is usually a bad idea.  Get it working first, then optimize.

Comment: Agreed on optimization last but that's what this is, I have a working version that does it individually as you suggested. 

I am a student; after showing the professors that I am creating this for, they wanted me to bundle them all together and run them in a batch and I assumed the reason was efficiency. Thanks for the help so far though.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert your own separators by issuing some extra queries, for example `select '-----';` between the real queries.

Writing results of individual queries to local files is not yet possible, but there is already a feature request for it ([IMPALA-2073](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-2073)). You can, however, easily save query results into HDFS as CSV files. You just have to create a new table to store the results specifying `row format delimited fields terminated by ','`, then use `insert into table [...] select [...]` to populate it. Please refer to the documentation sections [Using Text Data Files with Impala Tables](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_txtfile.html) and [INSERT Statement](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_insert.html) for details.

One comment suggested running the individual queries as separate commands and saving their results into separate CSV files. If you choose this solution, please be aware that DDL statements like `create table` are only guaranteed to take immediate effect in the connection in which they were issued. This means that creating a table and then immediately querying it in another impala shell is prone to failure. Even if you find that it works correctly, it may fail the next time you run it. On the other hand, running such queries one after the other in the same shell is always okay.